# problem with `uvm_do_with: can't generate more data

Tags: uvm

I met a problem with data constraint in UVM `uvm_do_with. I have a piece of code like this:

a) first I defined a data item:

```
class eth_item_data extends uvm_sequence_item;
    ...
    rand int              tx_len;
    rand logic [7:0]      txd[0:1500];
    ...

    constraint txd_range_c { foreach (txd[i]) txd[i] <=255;
                             foreach (txd[i]) txd[i] >=0;
                            } 
endclass
```

b) then I generated the data in the sequence:

```
class base_seq extends uvm_sequence #(eth_item_data);
    ...
    virtual task body();
      ...
      data_obj = eth_item_data::type_id::create("data_obj");
      `uvm_do_with (data_obj, {...
                               txd[0][7:0]==8'h11;
                               txd[1][7:0]==8'h22;
                               txd[2][7:0]==8'h33;
                               txd[3][7:0]==8'h44;
                               ...
                               txd[109][7:0]==8'hff;
                              }
                   )
    endtask
endclass
```

It is very strange that:
Q1): With code above it will shows randomize method call failed. The simulator implies `uvm_do_with constraint conflicts with these:

> These variables contribute to the set of conflicting constraints:
>     rand variables:
>       txd[1501] ......

Q2): if I only generate data with a small number, such as

```
      `uvm_do_with (data_obj, {...
                               txd[0][7:0]==8'h11;
                               txd[1][7:0]==8'h22;
                               txd[2][7:0]==8'h33;
                               txd[3][7:0]==8'h44;
                               txd[4][7:0]==8'h55;
                               txd[5][7:0]==8'h66;
                               txd[6][7:0]==8'h77;
                               txd[7][7:0]==8'h88;
                               }
                    )
```

data could be generated. This confused me. Can anybody help me to understand why I can't generate data with more? thanks.

Comment: I made an [MCVE] on [EDA Playground](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3VxC). (It would have been better had you done so.) It appears to work on the 3 simulators on EDA Playground. What is my [MCVE] missing?

Comment: Which simulator are you using?

Comment: this may be caused by some "hidden control character" in my source code, which I can't find. When I re-type all code word by word, it is ok now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear you've got it sorted.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite the test word by word and then I re-compiled the code. This time there is no issues. I guess this problem is caused by some "hidden typo" in the source which doesn't show, such as some control characters. Thanks for those comments, which give me a reminder.